# Spring responseBody not working with IE

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, response

I'm trying to use responseBody annotation to return xml in controller.Every browser works fine except IE(I'm using IE 9 in windows 7 x64). I found that it will request several times and then failed in request.Hope some of you haved encounter this and offer some help.
My code as followed:
UserController.java.This is just a simple controller,returning an object that represent User.

```
package com.spring;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class UserController
{

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public @ResponseBody
    User getUser()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("shun");
        user.setPassword("123123");
        return user;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
class User
{
    private String name;
    private String password;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I used spring-servlet.xml as my spring configuration file.
As following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
        <property name="parameterName" value="return_fmt"></property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <property name="marshaller">
                        <ref bean="castorMarshaller" />
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />

</beans>
```

By the way, my spring version is 3.1.0.And I also used 3.0.7 for test,just the same result.
After I started my project,I use chrome,firefox to visit it ,everything is fine.But When I try visiting it in IE 9,it shows me this result.

Can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: Dump the response using Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and post as an update.

Comment: Hi,Jordon,Thanks for your reply.I used fiddler to check the response header.It shows like:   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/xaml+xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2012 05:47:58 GMT

70
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><user><name>shun</name><password>123123</password></user>
0
I seems everything's ok.But I can't see the result in IE.

Comment: Is IE sending an appropriate Accept header for content negotiation?

Comment: Accept header seems ok.I use IE 7,IE8 mode with their response header is application/xaml+xml,the request not works by returning the result "application is down".When I changed to IE 9 or IE 9 compatible mode with their response header is application/xml,everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not your controller. I think the problem is only that IE does not display the XML content.

In IE: after you send the request and get the response, open the context menu and click on "show source code" (*or something like this, I have only a german IE*).

Comment: Thank you,Ralph.I used IE and found that only the response header is application/xhtml+xml and the result will be display,otherwise(the response header is application/xaml+xml) the browser will show that your application is down and not return anything about the result.But in fact,the result is returned when I used fiddler to check.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I use produces option on requestMapping solves it.
This forces spring return application/xml format result,then IE may display it.